# Add an asterisk to a label if field is required

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a label that I want to add an asterisk to if field is required. I have tried applying `ng-class` like so

```
<div class="col-xs-12 top5"  ng-if="(activity.itemType=='TEXTAREA')">
     <label class="col-xs-3 control-label text-right" for="act4{{$index}}"
            ng-class="{'asterisk-if-mandatory': data[$index].mandatory}">{{activity.itemLabel}}</label>
     <div class="col-xs-9">
         <textarea ng-model="activityItems[$index].value"
                   ng-required="data[$index].mandatory" cols="40" rows="6"
                   id="act4{{$index}}" name="txtComments" class="defaultTextareaInput"></textarea>
     </div>
</div>
```

and then css

```
.asterisk-if-mandatory {
    content: " *"
}
```

Any solutions?

Comment: As I don't know angular… What will be the rendered output of `ng-class="{'asterisk-if-mandatory': data[$index].mandatory}"` ?

Comment: put it on an after: `.asterisk-if-mandatory:after { content: " *"; display:inline-block; }` If your ng class is applied

Comment: Great stuff @Pete!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really know Angular…
But I would say you can do something like this, using pseudo-element `::after`:

```css
label {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}

label.asterisk-if-mandatory::after {
  content: " *";
}
```

```html
<label class="asterisk-if-mandatory">Item is mandatory</label>
<label class="">Item is not mandatory</label>
<label class="asterisk-if-mandatory">Item is mandatory</label>
```

(I reduced the code to the minimum required for the snippet)

Comment: To help a bit - the ng-class of `{'asterisk-if-mandatory': data[$index].mandatory}`  will dynamically add a standard CSS class `asterisk-if-mandatory` it `data[$index].mandatory` is truthy.  So, the class to be focused on is `asterisk-if-mandatory`....